# VueJS Template Syntax in VSCode

Tags: vuejs3, vscode-extensions

I'm a beginner user of VueJS and am trying to improve my workflow while learning the functionality of VueJS.

Currently, I am using VSCode, however, I am having a bit of trouble getting VSCode to recognize certain syntax.

For example, I am making a test template that looks like this: [image]

However, I would like to find an extension or setting that could make it look like this for improved readability: [image]

I have only ever used IntelliJ up until this point, so I'm having trouble figuring out how to accomplish this using VSCode.

I have tried using extensions like ESLint, Volar for typescript and VueJS, Vetur, and a few others. None of them have been able to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: Try `Vue 3 Support - All In One`. But I think Vetur and other tools you have used should work as well. Maybe something is wrong with the VSCode config? Do you see any errors in the VSCode console?

Comment: Where are you writing your code? `.vue` files or `.js`?

Comment: Give a try if using JS files: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Tobermory.es6-string-html

Comment: I'm writing in a .js file, I tried Vue 3 Support - All in One and es6-string-html as well. None of them seem to work. Additionally, I'm not seeing any errors in the extension service log.

Comment: If you're writing in a `.js` file, don't expect marvelous IDE support. Any blocker regarding the usage of `.vue` files? Will have less limitations + get an easier life.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll look into it now